# problem with calling the method after pressing the key

Tags: java, swing, canvas, keylistener

I would like to implement KeyListiner so that when pressing Space key program would generate new object of Function class and draw new image representing this function. For now program is working but pressing space key does not allow to generate a new image. Every advice will be greatly appreciated :)

Main class:

```
public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame(SOFTWARE_TITLE);
        MainView mainView = new MainView();
        Key key = new Key();
        Controller controller = new Controller(mainView);
        key.setController(controller);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(790, 580);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.add(mainView);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

MainView class:

```
public class MainView extends JPanel {

    private Function function;

    public MainView(){
        super();
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(200, 200);
        function = new Function();

        DrawBoard drawBoard = new DrawBoard(function);
        drawBoard.setSize(500, 500);
        drawBoard.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        drawBoard.setLocation(250, 20);
        add(drawBoard);

        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

DrawBoard class:

```
public class DrawBoard extends Canvas {

    short CUSTOM_WIDTH = 5 * 100;
    private Function function;

    public DrawBoard(Function function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        double difference = function.getzMax() - function.getzMin();

        for (int indexX = 0; indexX < 100; indexX++) {
            for (int indexY = 0; indexY < 100; indexY++) {
                double value = function.getPoints()[indexX][indexY].getZ() - function.getzMin();
                double corrected = setFloatInRGBRange(difference, value);
                g.setColor(intToColor((int) corrected));
                g.fillRect(indexX * 5, CUSTOM_WIDTH - ((indexY+1) * 5), 5, 5);
            }
        }
    }

    public Color intToColor(int colNum){
        return new Color(colNum, colNum, colNum);
    }

    private int setFloatInRGBRange(double difference, double value){
        return (int) ((255 * value)/difference);
    }

}
```

Key class:

```
public class Key implements KeyListener {

    Controller controller;

    public void setController(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            controller.generateFormula();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
public class Controller {

    MainView mainView;

    public Controller(MainView mainView) {
        this.mainView = mainView;
    }

    public void generateFormula() {
        this.mainView = new MainView();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. draw in the paintComponent method of a JPanel. 2. Don't mix Swing and AWT components (in other words, get rid of Canvas and use JPanel). 3. Don't create new components in the controller, but new non-component things to draw in the drawing component.

Comment: Not sure why you want to use `Canvas` for something so simple, seems a lot like overkill for little to no benefit (and probably a few drawbacks).  You really should be using the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of `KeyListener`, but, as a general rule, you would need to actually register for the events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some other things that need be reviewed in code you posted. But for your main concern i guess you donc check Key strokes properly.

I would use `e.getKeyCode()` instead of `e.getKeyChar()` to check the event.

So your condition would be : `e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE`

it is out of topic, but :

1. Your use of `Function` in multiples classes is unnecessary. It could be used only in `DrawBoard`
2. Don't mix Swing and AWT components as other already advised